# C# NavigationService.Navigate navigate in folder?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to navigate in windows phone 8 to xaml file in a folder.

i got this code but didn't work:

```
string testXaml = "/Xaml.AboutUs.xaml";
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(testXaml, UriKind.Relative));
```

It says `"No XAML was found at the location"`

Comment: If something is buried within a folder, you need to use a forward slash:  `"/Xaml/AboutUs.xaml"` possibly? The URL structure will follow the file locations in your project structure (as in, the folder names).